# Estoy intentando actualizar una calificacion hacia una reseña que da el usuario

Tags: laravel, update, pivot, modelorelacional

Es decir en la tabla pivot review_grade, donde se relacionan, se debe actualizar pero llevo tiempo intentando y no me genera, ya que siempre o crea o elimina las que comparten cualquier id.

```
 if ($grade && $review) {
        // Buscar calificación por su letra
        $c_grade = Grade::where('letter', $grade)->first();

        if ($c_grade) {
            // Verificar si el usuario ya ha calificado esta reseña
            if (!$review->grades()->where('id_user', $idUser)->exists()) {
                $review->grades()->attach($c_grade, ['id_user' => $idUser]);
                return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Reseña calificada exitosamente.');
            } else {
                $new_grade = $c_grade->id_grade;

                $review->grades()->updateExistingPivot($review->id_review, ['id_grade' => $new_grade]);
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Se ha cambiado la calificacion que le diste');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Calificación no encontrada.');
        }
    }
```

esa seria una parte de la funcion para realizar la actualizacion, el segundo if si se cumple pero ahorita el updateExisting no hace nada.

```
 public function grades()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class, 'review_grade', 'id_review', 'id_grade');
}
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Review::class, 'review_grade', 'id_grade', 'id_review');
}
```

Esas son funciones en los model para relacionar, nunca he usado pivot asi que estoy muy perdido

Comment: Me parece que updateExistingPivot es para las columnas que no son las claves foraneas. Para actualizar la fk podrías usar sync https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Comment: ah si, gracias, al final si fui a la documentacion y use syncWithoutDetaching y tuve que replantear como hacia el update, o sea estaba usando review y grades, pero era mejor usar review y user para actualizar grades. No se si me explique bien

Comment: Genial. Por favor agrega una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) explicando como lo resolviste y marcala como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita. De esa manera puede servir a otros usuarios con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final solo tuve que usar syncwithoutdetaching para que encontrara la relacion en la tabla pivot y en vez de eliminar o crear, actualizara;

```
 public function calificar_review(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $idUser = auth()->user()->id_user; // Obtener el ID del usuario autenticado
    $grade = $request->input('grade');//obtener la letra que se paso en el request
    $review = Review::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();//encontrar la reseña calificada
    if ($grade && $review) {
        // Buscar calificación por su letra
        $c_grade = Grade::where('letter', $grade)->firstOrFail();
        if (!$review->user()->wherePivot('id_user', $idUser)->exists()) {
            $review->user()->syncWithoutDetaching([
                $idUser => [
                    'id_grade' => $c_grade->id_grade,
                    ],
            ]);
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Reseña calificada exitosamente.');
        } else {
            //logica para cambiar la calificacion
            $new_grade = $c_grade->id_grade; //agregamos la id de la calificacion a una variable
            // funcion sync sin hacer un detach, donde se relaciona muchos a muchos review con user, de forma que nos da el pivot
            $review->user()->syncWithoutDetaching([$idUser =>['id_grade' => $new_grade]]);//le pasamos la fk idUser, y el arreglo del valor a cambiar
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Se ha cambiado la calificacion que le diste');
        }
    } else {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Error al calificar la reseña.');
}
```

}

Bueno, me funciona pero siento que no esta optimizado, si tuvieran sugerencias para mejorarlo.. lo agradeceria. Pero ahi lo que hace es identificar la reseña y el usuario para luego cambiar la calificacion